# Pressing [ENTER] in a form field that consists of an email address and password for login in the app causes the form to bypass validators and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

This is my Jquery file for DOM manipulation it basically checks for the written pattern in the form expecting a proper user email.
On mobile, if you paste a value into a form field: It doesn't correctly validate the input on submission. The console does not seem to spit anything wrong either

```
 (function ($) {
    // $.validator (target) - makes it possible to not show the error when a required field is empty until the form is submitted
    $.validator = function (target) {
        $(document).on ("keydown keyup blur", target, function (event) {
            if (!$(this).is ("textarea")) {
                var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if(code == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault ();
                    event.stopPropagation ();
                    if (event.type == 'keyup') {
                        $(this).closest("form").find ("input[type='submit']").trigger ("mousedown");
                        $(this).closest ("form").trigger ("submit");
                    }
                    return false;
                 }
            }
            var valid = true;
            if ($(this).val ().length > 0)
                $(this).attr ("data-empty", null);
            if (typeof $(this).attr ('required') != 'undefined' && typeof $(this).attr ('data-empty') == 'undefined') {
                if ($(this).val ().length == 0) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            if (typeof $(this).attr ('pattern') != 'undefined') {
                if ($(this).val ().search (new RegExp ('^' + $(this).attr ("pattern") + '$')) == -1 && typeof $(this).attr ('data-empty') == 'undefined') {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            if (valid) {
                $(this).siblings ("span.error").removeAttr ('style');
                $(this).removeClass ("invalid");
            } else {
                $(this).siblings ("span.error").css ('visibility', 'visible');
                $(this).addClass ("invalid");
            }
        });
        $(document).on ("mousedown", "input[type='submit']", function (event) {
            var form = $(this).closest ("form");
            form.attr ("data-valid", "false");
            form.find ("[data-empty]").each (function () {
                $(this).attr ('data-empty', null);
            })
            var valid = true;
            console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation start');
            console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation checking disabled');
            if (!(typeof form.find ("input[type='submit']").attr ("disabled") == 'undefined' || form.find ("input[type='submit']").attr ("disabled") == 'false')) {
                console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation submit disabled');
                valid = false;
                event.preventDefault ();
                event.stopPropagation ();
            }
            console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation checking required');
            form.find ("*[required]").each (function () {
                console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation required ' + $(this).attr ("name"));
                if ($(this).attr ("required") != 'false' && $(this).val ().length == 0) {
                    valid = false;
                    console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation required fail');
                    event.preventDefault ();
                    event.stopPropagation ();
                    $(this).siblings ("span.error").css ('visibility', 'visible');
                    $(this).addClass ("invalid");
                }
            });
            console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation checking pattern');
            form.find ("*[pattern]").each (function () {
                console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation pattern ' + $(this).attr ("name") + ' ' + $(this).attr ("pattern"));
                if ($(this).val ().search (new RegExp ($(this).attr ("pattern"))) == -1) {
                    valid = false;
                    console.log (new Date().getTime () + ' formValidation pattern fail');
                    event.preventDefault ();
                    event.stopPropagation ();
                    $(this).siblings ("span.error").css ('visibility', 'visible');
                    $(this).addClass ("invalid");
                }
            });
            if (valid) form.attr ("data-valid", "true");
            event.preventDefault ();
            event.stopPropagation ();
            return false;
        });
    }
    $.extend ($.validator, {
        fix : function (target) {
            $(target).each (function () {
                if (typeof $(this).attr ('required') != 'undefined' && $(this).val ().length == 0) {
                    $(this).attr ("data-empty", "true");
                    $(this).siblings ("span.error").css ('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $.fn.validator = function (target) {
        $.validator (target);
        return this;
    }
    })(jQuery);
```

This is my validator jst that is triggered when submitting the form

```
function customValidator () {
    setTimeout (function () {
        if (typeof $.validator != 'undefined') {
            $.validator ("input, textarea, select");
            $.validator.fix ("input, textarea, select");
        } else {
            customValidator ();
        }
    }, 200);
}
customValidator ();
```

Am i doing this the wrong way?
Is there any easier way of implementing a more concise validator ?